# why does e raised to the power of negative infinity equal 0?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponentiation, infinity

Why is it that e raised to the power of negative infinity would equal 0 instead of negative infinity? I am working on problems with regards to limits of integration, specifically improper integrals and a little confused as to what things approach infinity our negative infinity versus approaching zero

Comment: "Negative infinity" is **not** a number, so "e raised to the power of negative infinity" is nothing. What you want to know is «why is $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}e^x=0$?».

Comment: The principle root of a positive number raised to any real power (positive or negative) is positive.  Consider the phrase more as $\lim\limits_{n\to -\infty} e^{n} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^n}$.  You should know that $e$ raised to a "large" number is "large", and 1 divided by a "large" number is very near zero.

Comment: Ok, because I was thinking of it like a zero, e raised to zero =1, so e raised to negative infinity = nothing

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez has said exactly what you need. Another way to see this is to look at the graph of $y=e^{x}$. Isn't there a horizontal asymptote towards the left (i.e., as $x\to-\infty$, doesn't $y$ settle?)?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez and jmoravitz the combo of your comments help make this very clear! Thank you

Comment: $e^{-\infty}=\dfrac1{e^\infty}=\dfrac1{\infty}=0$.

Comment: One could say it depends which infinity you mean, and which definition of “$ exp $” or “$ e^x $”! If we choose [Kruskal’s definition of $ exp $ for Surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number#Exponential_function), we find $ \exp \omega = \omega ^ \omega $ and $ \exp (x+y) = \exp x \times \exp y $, whence $ \exp {-\omega} = \frac 1 {\omega ^ \omega } \neq 0 $.

Comment: Lucian's rigorous proof says it all.   What would  1^-infinity be?

Answer (score 15):

First of all: $-\infty$ is not a  number and you should always be cautious when you use it as if it were one. This means you should not read $e^{-\infty}$ as an exponentiation of two real numbers, but as an answer to the question

> If I compute $e^{-N}$ for really *really* big values of $N$, what does my result look like (approach to)?

Mathematicians write this as the question for the value $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x}$.
Perhaps you know (from a different answer) that

$$e^{-N}=\frac1{e^N}$$

and that $e^N$ is enormously bigger than $N$ for large values of $N$. This means that $1/e^N$ is very *very* small, i.e. close to zero. And it comes closer to zero if we make $N$ larger. At no point it crosses the zero. This brings us to the conclusion that $e^{-\infty}$ is *considered* to be zero because

1. no bigger number makes sense. E.g. assume $e^{-\infty}=0.0001$. But already $e^{-10}<0.0001$. It makes no sense to make $e^{-\infty}$ bigger than that because bigger values of $N$ should make $e^{-N}$ smaller. And you will always find such a contradiction if you do not choose $e^{-\infty}=0$.
2. no negative number makes sense because this would be some kind of a *jump* in the function. We are *always* above zero, and *suddenly* we should be below zero? This sounds strange for a nice (that is, continuous) function like $e^x$.

Also if you look at the graph of $e^{-x}$ you see that it approaches $0$ as $x\to\infty$.

[image]

Additionally $e^x$ is known for being positive everywhere (on the real line). This does not mean that $e^{-\infty}=0$, but it makes the choice $e^{-\infty}=-\infty$ very unnatural.

Comment: Good explanation of limit as n->infinite to a beginner!

Answer (score 14):

Note that: $e^{k} = \dfrac{1}{e^{-k}}$. Thus if $k \to -\infty \Rightarrow -k \to +\infty$, and $e^{-k} \to +\infty$ because $e^{-k} > -k$, and the as the latter approaches $+\infty$, so does the former, hence $e^k=\dfrac{1}{e^{-k}} \to 0$.